# React run through a Json list Error

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

In my React component I try to run through a Json list.

**I get this error:**
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.options.map is not a function

My component:

```
var BookingTimes = class extends React.Component {
                     render() {
                     var options = this.props.testop.map(function (app, index) {
                        return (                     
                           <div>
                              <div>{app.AdvisorName+"-"+app.AppointmentID +"-"+app.AppointmentStart}</div>   
                           </div>   
                        )
                    }.bind(this));

                    return <div>
                      {options}
                    </div>;
                }
            }
```

This is how my Json dataList looks

```
var testop = {
                "AdvisorBookingTimeSlots": {
                    "AdvisorName": "Ole",
                    "AvaliabltTime": {
                        "AppointmentViewModel": [
                          {
                              "AppointmentID": "AAMkADJlMjEyNjFmLTQ3MzItNDFkYy05OGNhLWIxNjRiOTFhYzBiZQFRAAgI1JG3V41AAEYAAAAA7Ld9io5oYU2bLEN/OnmA/wcA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAABDQAA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAFWgQAAEA==",
                              "AppointmentStart": "2017-05-03T08:00:00+02:00"
                          },
                          {
                              "AppointmentID": "AAMkADJlMjEyNjFmLTQ3MzItNDFkYy05OGNhLWIxNjRiOTFhYzBiZQFRAAgI1JG3V41AAEYAAAAA7Ld9io5oYU2bLEN/OnmA/wcA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAABDQAA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAFWggAAEA==",
                            "AppointmentStart": "2017-05-03T10:30:00+02:00"
                         },
                         {
                                   "AppointmentID": "AAMkADJlMjEyNjFmLTQ3MzItNDFkYy05OGNhLWIxNjRiOTFhYzBiZQFRAAgI1JG3V41AAEYAAAAA7Ld9io5oYU2bLEN/OnmA/wcA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAABDQAA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAFWhQAAEA==",
                              "AppointmentStart": "2017-05-03T19:00:00+02:00"
                       }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what the error is caused by ?

In fiddler my jsonlist look like this:

```
{
    "AdvisorName": "Ole",
    "AvaliabltTime": [
        {
            "AppointmentID": "AAMkADJlMjEyNjFmLTQ3MzItNDFkYy05OGNhLWDVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAFWgQAAEA==",
            "AppointmentStart": "2017-05-03"
        },
        {
            "AppointmentID": "U2bLEN/OnmA/wcA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAABDQAA4DVIr7RapkG0++wSr388EQAAAAFWggAAEA==",
            "AppointmentStart": "2017-05-03"
        },
        {
            "AppointmentID": "AAMkADJlMjEyNjFmLTQ3MzItNDFkYy05OGNhLWpkG0++wSr388EQAAAAFWhQAAEA==",
            "AppointmentStart": "2017-05-03"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How is `<BookingTimes>` being used?

Comment: Are you passing `testop` as props? Even if you are, then also its an object, not array

Comment: Your "Json dataList" is neither JSON or a list - it's just a plain ol' JavaScript object.

Comment: I have updated my question. My Json data in fiddler

Answer (score 0):

You likely aren't passing in the props to the `<BookingTimes>` component.

```
<BookingTypes testop={testop} />
```

What is happening is you are tryng to read properties off of `this.props` which if you don't pass any in, will be undefined (and you can't call a function on undefined).

***If*** your data does *not need* to be passed in and lives in the same file as the `BookingTypes` component you don't need to use `this.props`.

```
var options = testop.map(...
```

**Edit**: As it was pointed out by @Priyesh Kumar, `testop` is an object and you will not be able to use `.map` on anything but an array.

Comment: oooooh now I pass testop as props.

But now i get this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.options.map is not a function

Comment: Because `testop` is an object. Objects in JS don't have the `.map` function -- only arrays do.

Comment: Are you sure `.map` is what you want to be using here? What goal are you trying to reach? Do you only want to itterate over the collection of `AppointmentViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there is a problem with handling your `testop` structure. If you pass variable `testop` as prop, then you can call `map()` only `AppointmentViewModel`, which is a nested property, so the correct map would look like:
`this.props.testop.AdvisorBookingTimeSlots.AvaliabltTime.AppointmentViewModel.map(..)`

This is rather ugly code, and a possible cause of some

> cannot read property of undefined

errors.

I would suggest you restructure your component to something like this:

```
var BookingTimes = class extends React.Component {
                     render() {
                     var options = this.props.appointmentViewModel.map(function (app, index) {
                        return (                     
                           <div>
                              <div>{this.props.advisorName+"-"+app.AppointmentID +"-"+app.AppointmentStart}</div>   
                           </div>   
                        )
                    }.bind(this));

                    return <div>
                      {options}
                    </div>;
                }
            }
```

and you would instantializa your component like this

```
<BookingTimes 
    appointmentViewModel={testop.AdvisorBookingTimeSlots.AvaliabltTime.AppointmentViewModel}
    advisorName={testop.AdvisorBookingTimeSlots.AdvisorName}
/>
```

You can tweak this solution more to add null checks, or consider using lodash's `get` method for safely accessing nested properties.

Hope this helps!